# how do I access an array posted from a curl post?

Tags: php, curl, pdo

Here is the scenario I am posting to a PHP file via curl.
What is getting sent is an array. Since this is happening programmatically I do not know how to view the array/payload on the receiving side.

```
post_to_url("http://example.com/lead/post_data.php", $data);
```

My understanding is this is a JSON array but I am not even certain the payload is not being sent to post_data.php

how do I troubleshoot this? Normally I would do a var dump but since I am not present I am confused as to how I can accomplish this.
I was thinking something like this:

```
$array = json_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['$array']));
print_r($array[0]);
```

But printing this will now show me anything obviously if I load the page. how can I log the array being posted?

in the end, I want to take the array and save it to a MySQL database with PDO.

Comment: to debug external calls to you script, you can dump entire $_POST into file and look into this file after request

Comment: you can try the input stream if `$_POST` is empty `file_get_contents('php://input')`

Answer (score 2):

The $_POST variable only captures serialized post data. If the post request is in json format, it's probably in the body of the request and will be accessible by looking at

```
var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

If so you can `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

Comment: Thanks! saved me the work of posting it.  I had the same thoughts.

Comment: Sorry, I posted it before I saw your comment. You're absolutely right on. This was something I was fighting through a couple months ago when someone was using angularjs to make calls to my api even though the specs called for serialized post data.

Comment: No worries, it was at the same time.  It's cool with me.  I have dealt with it many times, they are not setting the content-type to `application/json` ( I think that causes this ) in the return headers.

Comment: I don't understand how I can var_dump from my server from a script that was posted from a 2nd server.

Comment: If ArtisticPheonix and I didn't answer the question you meant to ask it would be helpful if you rephrase the question. Do you have access to the server that receives the cURL? Where do you define the function `post_to_url()`? When you say 'The array' are you talking about on the server that's posting the request or the one that is capturing the request? Which server are you using to save the result to a database?

Comment: `serialized` in `application/x-www-urlencoded` format, OR `multipart/form-data`-format, to be specific. if it is in any other format (like JSON or XML), it won't be in $_POST